# Validator Callout Control Using Javascript for section of page not full page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, validation

I am wondering how I can tell the validation validator controls to trigger the validation only n sections of the page. For example, we have an accordian. I only want the accordian section to be validated at a time, not every validator control on the page. I am triggering it from javascript client side liek the following:

```
if (Page_ClientValidate()) {
    console.log("page is valid");
    return true;
}
else {
    hideValidatorCallout();
    return false;
}
```

For an example control as this:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="valLocatorWebsite" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbxWebsite"
   ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid website address." Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Small"
   ValidationExpression="^([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w-./?%&=]*)?">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
<cc1:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="vceWebsite" runat="server" TargetControlID="valLocatorWebsite" Enabled="True">
```

Is there a grouping attribute or property for this control, or how can I target to only validate certain ones at a time?

Answer (score 0):

I just found what I was looking for. There is an attribute called ValidationGroup.

```
<asp:Button ID=”btnSave” runat=”server” ValidationGroup=”tabPersonal,
tabContact” CommandName=”Insert” OnClick=”btnSave_Click” OnClientClick=”switchToTab();” />
```

This is what I was looking for. An example with javascript can be found here:https://rakeshbajania.wordpress.com/2009/10/25/applying-validation-in-tab-control-of-ajax-toolkit/

And is used with javascript like so:

```
if (Page_ClientValidate('your validation group name')) {
    console.log("page is valid");
    return true;
}
else {
    hideValidatorCallout();
    return false;
}
```